# "Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in theme.inc"

Tags: theming

i am adding custom modules in drupal 7. while creating a custom table i got the error like this
"Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in /srv/bindings/code/includes/theme.inc on line 2002"

```
            $form = array();
            $headers = array(t('Teacher Name'), t('Paypal Id '),  t('Status'), t('Action'));
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `users_roles` ur JOIN `users` u ON u.uid=ur.uid WHERE rid=4";
            $rs = db_query($query);
            $row = array();
            if ($rs) {
                  foreach($rs as $data) {
                    $name = $data->name;
                    $mail = $data->mail;
                    $status = $data->status ;
                    $row[] = array(stripslashes(ucwords($data->name)), $mail, $status, 
                    "<a href='#'>" . t('Pay Now') . "</a>  " );
                }}
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($headers);
                print_r($row);
            return theme_table('table', array('header' => $headers, 'rows' => $row));
```

I dont know where i done mistake. Please give some ideas.

Comment: This error happens when you try to access a variable like an array when
the variable was initialised with a different type than array.
That was clear as the PHP Error discribes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `theme_table` directly instead of `theme`, but still passing the name in.

Use this instead:

```
return theme('table', array('header' => $headers, 'rows' => $row));
```

Or even better (depending on context), a [render array](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/render-arrays/render-arrays-overview).

Answer (score 0):

```
        $form = array();
        $headers = array(t('Teacher Name'), t('Paypal Id '),  t('Status'), t('Action'));
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users_roles` ur JOIN `users` u ON u.uid=ur.uid WHERE rid=4";
        $rs = db_query($query);
        $row = array();
        if ($rs) {
              $result = $rs->fetchAll();
              foreach($result as $data) {
                $name = $data->name;
                $mail = $data->mail;
                $status = $data->status ;
                $row[] = array(stripslashes(ucwords($data->name)), $mail, $status, 
                "<a href='#'>" . t('Pay Now') . "</a>  " );
            }}
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($headers);
            print_r($row);
        return theme_table('table', array('header' => $headers, 'rows' => $row));
```

Now, it will work correctly for you.

Comment: Hi ashish,
thanks for your comment. But still i got error like this
"atal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in /srv/bindings/c90e433b09414ab9a209102a3246bcae/code/includes/theme.inc on line 2002"

Comment: please verify the code now. I have edited my code.

Comment: yes i changed  "foreach($result as $data) {" this

Comment: Are you still getting that error?

Comment: yes ashish still error is coming

Answer (score 0):

You don't report exactly which line is causing the error, but if it is between the lines you shown, then the line causing the error is the following one.

```
return theme_table('table', array('header' => $headers, 'rows' => $row));
```

It happens because [`theme_table()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_table/7.x), as any other theme function, is expecting an array as first argument, not a string.

The correct line would be the following one.

```
return theme('table', array('header' => $headers, 'rows' => $row));
```

Keep in mind that on Drupal you never directly call a theme function like `theme_table()` because the theme function for generating a table could not be that. In fact, modules can change the theme function called from [theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme/7.x) by implementing [`hook_theme_registry_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7.x).

Then, in Drupal 7 is possibile to return a render array, instead of a string. Instead of  `return theme_table('table', array('header' => $headers, 'rows' => $row));` you can use `return array('#theme' => 'table', '#header' => $headers, '#rows' => $row);` in most of the cases.